# How to upload SOFT files in Orange?

Tags: data, orange

I have a dataset which I obtained from NCBI, but it is a SOFT file. When I upload the SOFT file to the file widget in Orange, it cannot be uploaded. Is there a way to upload SOFT files in Orange?